# Android PreferencesActivity showing previous fragment

Tags: android, android-preferences

I created a Preferences screen by extending PreferencesActivity as per the example [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html).

The first screen appears okay but when I click to see the second screen I see them one on top of the other.
So, taking advice from a number of other thread, I changed the background of the second fragment to black.

This worked in as much as I no longer see them both. But instead I see the FIRST one only except for the header.

The first screen looks like this:

[image]

and the second one looks like this:

[image]

Only the header line changed whereas the rest remained the same.

This is the code in my activity:

```
public class SettingsActivity  extends PreferenceActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Load the preferences from an XML resource
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new PreferencesMain()).commit();


}

/**
 * This fragment contains a second-level set of preference that you
 * can get to by tapping an item in the first preferences fragment.
 */
public static class PreferencesMain extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Load the preferences from an XML resource
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        View view = getView();
        view.setBackgroundColor(ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(),android.R.color.black, null));
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        view.setBackgroundColor(ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(),android.R.color.black, null));
    }
}

/**
 * This fragment contains a second-level set of preference that you
 * can get to by tapping an item in the first preferences fragment.
 */
public static class PreferencesNotifications extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Load the preferences from an XML resource
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences_notifications);

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        View view = getView();
        view.setBackgroundColor(ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(),android.R.color.black, null));
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        view.setBackgroundColor(ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(),android.R.color.black, null));
    }
}

@Override
protected boolean isValidFragment (String fragmentName) {
    return true;
}

}
```

preferences.xml

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<PreferenceCategory
    android:title="@string/settings_notifications">

    <!-- This PreferenceScreen tag sends the user to a new fragment of
         preferences.  If running in a large screen, they can be embedded
         inside of the overall preferences UI. -->
    <PreferenceScreen
        android:fragment="activities.SettingsActivity$PreferencesNotifications"
        android:title="@string/settings_notifications_managePushTitle"
        android:summary="@string/settings_notifications_managePushSummary">
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        <!-- Arbitrary key/value pairs can be included for fragment arguments -->
        <extra android:name="someKey" android:value="somePrefValue" />
    </PreferenceScreen>

</PreferenceCategory>
```

preferences_notifications.xml

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<PreferenceCategory
    android:title="@string/settings_notifications_managePushHeader">

<CheckBoxPreference
    android:key="checkbox_preference"
    android:title="@string/settings_notifications_managePushEntry1Title"
    android:summary="@string/settings_notifications_managePushEntry1Summary" />
</PreferenceCategory>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `header.xml` to manage settings, and use `onBuildHeaders` method.

Resource **headers.xml**:

```
<preference-headers xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <header android:title="Digle"
        android:fragment="activities.SettingsActivity$PreferencesMain"/>
</preference-headers>
```

Class **SettingsActivity**:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Remove all code in here
    }

    @Override
    public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
        super.onBuildHeaders(target);
        loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.headers, target);
    }

    ...
}
```

**EDIT:**
An alternative could be use [subscreens](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#Subscreens). You have to place the group of `Preference` objects inside a `PreferenceScreen`.

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:key="Settings"
                  android:title="@string/app_name">
    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="@string/settings_notifications">

        <PreferenceScreen
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:summary="@string/settings_notifications_managePushSummary"
            android:title="@string/settings_notifications_managePushTitle">

            <PreferenceCategory
                android:title="@string/settings_notifications_managePushHeader">

                <CheckBoxPreference
                    android:key="checkbox_preference"
                    android:summary="@string/settings_notifications_managePushEntry1Summary"
                    android:title="@string/settings_notifications_managePushEntry1Title"/>

            </PreferenceCategory>

        </PreferenceScreen>

    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: Problem with that is that my preferences are not only headers. I have some "normal" preferences mixed in.

Comment: Then, you could try "subscreens".

Comment: Isn't that what I am doing? Maybe I am missing something (in fact I am almost certainly missing something).

Comment: Try to put all code inside one "setting" file, I edited my answer.

Comment: Okay. I'll give it a shot and get back with the results.

Comment: Just tried it (was on vacation) and it works.
Many thanks.